# MYSQL COUNT & SUM every CASE possible

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I have mysql query like this....

```
    "SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN ticket_source='bpt' THEN tix_tickets.ticket_price END) AS bpt_money,
COUNT(CASE WHEN ticket_source='bpt' THEN 1 END) AS bpt_num,
SUM(CASE WHEN ticket_source='door' THEN tix_tickets.ticket_price END) AS door_money,
COUNT(CASE WHEN ticket_source='door' THEN 1 END) AS door_num,
SUM(CASE WHEN ticket_source='goldstar' THEN tix_tickets.ticket_price END) AS goldstar_money,
COUNT(CASE WHEN ticket_source='goldstar' THEN 1 END) AS goldstar_num,
COUNT(CASE WHEN ticket_price='0' THEN 1 END) AS free_tix,
COUNT(CASE WHEN ticket_price='10' THEN 1 END) AS ten_buck_tix,
COUNT(CASE WHEN ticket_price='20' THEN 1 END) AS twenty_buck_tix,
COUNT(CASE WHEN ticket_price='25' THEN 1 END) AS twentyfive_buck_tix
FROM tix_people,tix_tickets WHERE tix_people.ID=tix_tickets.holder_id GROUP BY ticket_date ORDER BY ticket_date"
```

And it works great, but I would like use every `ticket_price` in the table without calling them individually. I would like to get every `ticket_source` without calling them individually. I figure I can shorten my code and make it better now as I expand the number of sources and prices.

Comment: that all depends on how you want to pull the data out. if you want to pull it out with a column counting the number of ten_buck_tix then you have to write it out.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write out what columns you want to select. if you want to try and build a query you could do that. here is a little refactor of your select. I cleaned up some of the case statements to just use a boolean sum

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN ticket_source='bpt' THEN tix_tickets.ticket_price END) AS bpt_money,
    SUM(ticket_source='bpt') AS bpt_num,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ticket_source='door' THEN tix_tickets.ticket_price END) AS door_money,
    SUM(ticket_source='door') AS door_num,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ticket_source='goldstar' THEN tix_tickets.ticket_price END) AS goldstar_money,
    SUM(ticket_source='goldstar') AS goldstar_num,
    SUM(ticket_price='0') AS free_tix,
    SUM(ticket_price='10') AS ten_buck_tix,
    SUM(ticket_price='20') AS twenty_buck_tix,
    SUM(ticket_price='25') AS twentyfive_buck_tix
FROM tix_people
JOIN tix_tickets on tix_people.ID=tix_tickets.holder_id 
GROUP BY ticket_date 
ORDER BY ticket_date
```

Comment: Thank you. Much better already. Is there a way MySQL can find out how many values exist for "ticket_source" and automatically set a variable for sum of price and count of results for each ticket source?

Comment: no. mysql only does what you tell it to. so if you want to specify a count for all free tickets you have to manually do that yourself. that being said you could build a query by concatenating strings based off of the prices... but the query itself has to specify what to pull out and cant do that automatically